# Duplicating elements with Javascript and naming w/ counter

Tags: javascript, counter, getelementbyid, duplication

I think I've searched long enough to warrant asking this, and I hope I'm not missing something obvious, but I'm at my wits' end with this. I'm a complete JavaScript noob, and I'm having difficulty getting a script I found online to work correctly.

The project I was assigned was to make it so this form could be extended by clicking a button, and I thought I'd be able to accomplish it with HTML alone, but that doesn't seem possible. I found this script, and was able to get the duplication part of it to work:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html

However, the part of the script that's supposed to append a counter to the names of the fields isn't working, and therefore when the form is submitted, everything is recorded under the first form's `name` value. My guess is that that part of the script is trying to get the name of the wrong node, but I really don't know. Here's a shortened version of what I have. Ugly, but hopefully it gets the point across...

http://pastebin.com/nQhnXXKx

Let me know if I can clarify, and any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: You didn't close a `<td>` at one point. Actually, it's worse than that...you have a lot of invalid HTML

Comment: Also, don't you think you meant to use `window.onload = init;`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's more than likely a result of my chopping it up to make it simpler to sort through. My frustration is making me sloppy. I'll update it in a bit...

Comment: If it helps, this is how I'd change it for now: http://jsfiddle.net/gAaxS/

Comment: That is hugely helpful. I'll mess around with it and let you know the results...

Comment: Success! I was able to incorporate it into my page. You're a lifesaver @Ian!

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped and you got it working. I added an answer. Let me know if you need more help with it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorganizing the code, you could use something like this:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var counter, init, addWorkshop, renameInputs, removeWorkshop;

    counter = 0;

    init = function () {
        document.getElementById("moreWorkshops").onclick = addWorkshop;
        addWorkshop();
    };

    addWorkshop = function () {
        var clonedWorkshop, targetInsert;

        counter++;

        clonedWorkshop = document.getElementById("readroot").cloneNode(true);
        clonedWorkshop.id = "";
        clonedWorkshop.className = "";
        clonedWorkshop.querySelector(".remover").onclick = removeWorkshop;
        renameInputs(clonedWorkshop);

        targetInsert = document.getElementById("writeroot");
        targetInsert.parentNode.insertBefore(clonedWorkshop, targetInsert);
    };

    renameInputs = function (container) {
        var children, i, j, cur, theName;
        children = container.children;
        for (i = 0, j = children.length; i < j; i++) {
            cur = children[i];
            if (cur.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
                theName = cur.name;
                if (theName) {
                    cur.name = theName + counter;
                }
            } else {
                renameInputs(cur);
            }
        }
    };

    removeWorkshop = function () {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    };

    window.onload = init;
}());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gAaxS/

Note that this is very structure-specific - for example, the `this.parentNode.parentNode` means that it has exactly two ancestors that you want to target. If you changed the HTML, you'd have to change the JS (which is usual).